# First use of the term and principle of dynamic pressure — Daniel Bernoulli?

Tags: mathematics, physics

I have read in several places that both the developed concept and the term for [*dynamic pressure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_pressure) *as it pertain to fluid dynamics* was first published in [Hydrodynamica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrodynamica) by [Daniel_Bernoulli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Bernoulli), but I can not find any direct evidence of this. Assuming it is there, I assume that it would be in the original latin. Is there a linkable source where I could see it as originally written and defined? Either the original latin, or a scholarly translation into a different language if necessary.

If not a linkable source, even a screen shot of the relevant passage would also be helpful.

**below:** HYDRODYNAMICA, Danielis Bernoulli, [from here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:HYDRODYNAMICA,_Danielis_Bernoulli.png).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The experiment described in [Section 12, § 7](http://reader.digitale-sammlungen.de/de/fs1/object/display/bsb10871847_00274.html) of the "Hydrodynamica" and depicted in the [appendix](http://reader.digitale-sammlungen.de/de/fs1/object/display/bsb10871847_00339.html) (second picture from above on the left part of the page), can be described as follows: water flows out of a perforated tube and rises to the height of the water in a nearby manometer, thus establishing the equality of hydrostatic and hydrodynamic pressure. See also [Mikhailov](https://books.google.de/books?id=UdGBy8iLpocC&pg=PA134) in: Grattan-Guinness, "Landmark Writings in Western Mathematics 1640-1940", Elsevier 2005.

Daniel's as well as Johann Bernoulli's treatises on hydraulics were translated into [English](https://books.google.de/books/about/Hydrodynamics_and_Hydraulics.html?id=sJggAQAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y) by Carmody and Kobus.

See also the introduction to [Leonardo Euleri Opera Omnia, Ser. II, Vol. 12](https://books.google.de/books?id=sT1cHAAACAAJ), written by Clifford Truesdell.

Comment: OK I'm enjoying these links very much, thank you! I wonder if there is any place in *Hydrodynamica* where at least the $v^2$ behavior of the dynamic pressure is shown. The [simple form of the Bernoulli equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle#Incompressible_flow_equation) should have something that looks at least a bit like $v^2\rho/2 + p_{static}$ I'll keep reading...

Comment: I don't think so. Daniel was not as good a mathematician as his father Johann, his reasoning was more verbal. In Johann's work [Hydraulica](https://archive.org/stream/bub_gb_K6SSYGzj4u0C#page/n471/mode/2up), published in 1742, you will find more formulas and also the terms "vis hydrostatica" and "vis hydraulica" (see next page).

Comment: You've opened my eyes to the Bernoullis and their wide-ranging contributions, and to the idea that when researching something like *Bernoulli's Equation*, one doesn't necessarily find an explicit sentence such as "...and so my equation is:..." Thanks for your help!